# Problem with Save Data

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitableview

Hi I'm doing an RSS reader application but I want the information that shows the iphone on a table can be saved in a DB or a file. Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is... challenging, but I think you're looking to store data from your app persistently in a database, yes?

If that's the case, [let](http://iphonedevelopmentbits.com/tag/iphone-sqlite-tutorials) [me](http://iphonedevelopmentbits.com/tag/iphone-sqlite-tutorials) [introduce](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=453043) [you](http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/) [to](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/4086-my-iphone-sqlite-tutorial.html) [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iphone+sqlite).

If not, then I've just been a minor jackass for no reason, but regardless, please clarify the wording of your question.

Answer (score 0):

There a plenty of tutorials available for SQLite and the iPhone. Please search before asking a question here. Don't think to easy and just ask, try yourself and discover possibilities of the iPhone SDK, SQLite and all other stuff related to it.

We'll only be able to help you if you provide pages/links of all the sources you've consulted.

For what I can do now: please read (and understand/try/adjust it) [one of the many tutorials](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate over to the Apple site and check out the documentation called "[Getting Started With Data Management](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_DataManagement_iPhone/index.html)".

The problem with giving you an exact, step by step answer is that you haven't provided enough information.  You might be able to leverage any of the following technologies:

- User Preferences
- .plist files
- Core Data
- sqlite database

(these are listed in order of easiest to implement, but least featured at the top to the most robust solution at the bottom)

---

Based on the comments, I moved Core Data above sqlite

Comment: Do you really think it's easier to implement using sqlite than it is with Core Data?

Comment: Core Data is significantly easier to implement & maintain than SQLite, once you understand it.  The learning curve isn't particularly steep compared to SQLite either.  Even for folks that already know SQLite, there is a significant potential return on investment for learning CD.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  I moved Core Data above sqlite.  I had a strong sqlite background and just found it much easier than Core Data to initially learn.  But someone with a stronger OSX programmering background might be different.